# Can I have two versions of Ruby plus the correct DevKit?

Tags: ruby, devkit

I have Win 7 Pro. I have upgraded from Ruby 1.9.3 to 2.1.3, and the correct DevKit.

I now have problems with my Watir automated testing. In order to blame/absolve Ruby, I need to revert to Ruby 1.9.3 and the correct DevKit.

Is there an easy way to revert without deleting my current Ruby and Devkit?

I'm not a techie, but I think I can have two versions of Ruby in different folders simply by modifying the "Path" in Control Panel.

How would I maintain two versions of DevKit?

Further info:  I do not use Rails.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can temporary change the ruby in unix machine, try it in windows:

```
rvm list
```

will output something like this:

```
rvm rubies

ruby-1.8.7-p371 [ i686 ]
ruby-1.8.7-p374 [ i686 ]
ruby-1.9.3-p327 [ x86_64 ]
* ruby-1.9.3-p392 [ x86_64 ]
ruby-1.9.3-p484 [ x86_64 ]
ruby-2.0.0-p247 [ x86_64 ]
ruby-2.1.1 [ x86_64 ]
=> ruby-2.1.2 [ x86_64 ]

# => - current
# =* - current && default
#  * - default
```

as you see, my current ruby is 2.1.2, you can change it by typing

```
rvm use  ruby-1.9.3-p484
```

Comment: Marked as correct answer, because it pointed me in the correct direction. Info:  Various Google articles suggested that RVM with Windows is possible, but is likely to be outside my limited technical abilities. The same articles suggested `Pik`:
[link](http://rubyonwindowsguides.github.io/book/ch02-03.html) This is working fine :)

Comment: Use `uru` for windows now.